# What is the proper spelling of "Miranda Savage" from "Vision of the Future"?

Tags: star-wars, novel

I'm listening to the audiobook of *Vision of the Future* by Timothy Zahn (narrated by Marc Thompson, although that's not relevant to the question). There is a character working for Talon Karrde whose name is pronounced "Miranda Savage" (at least by Thompson). I've been trying to look her up and can't find one single shred of information on her, which means either nobody has written a Wookieepedia article about her or mentioned her on the web (nigh impossible to believe) or her name is spelled differently than you'd expect from hearing it (similar to Karrde).

All I'm looking for is the correct spelling of her name. It might be that it is actually spelled "Miranda Savage".

Please, no spoilers in answers or comments. It's been so long since I read it that I feel like I'm reading it for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [ebook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vision_of_the_Future) version:

> *“**Moranda Savich**,” she said. “Sort of a second-string employee of your
>   old friend Talon Karrde.*

And of course she has [her own Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Moranda_Savich)

> Moranda Savich, a Human woman, was a professional thief, con artist,
>   and master of disguise who worked independently and in association
>   with Talon Karrde's smuggling organization. In 0 BBY, she helped the
>   Rebel Alliance get information on the construction of the Death Star
>   I. In 19 ABY, though she was old enough to be a great-grandmother, she
>   played an active role in Karrde's efforts to assist the New Republic
>   during the Caamas Document crisis.

Comment: It figures. Thompson seems to clearly be saying "Miranda Savage", but maybe the next time I hear it I'll hear how Zahn writes it. Many thanks!